# Event Label As URL

Tags: macros, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Trying to understand Google Tag Manager. With some help from colleagues I have a GA installation set up using GTM.

The particular tag in question (custom html) is:

```
<script>
    $('.additional-content a').click(function(event){

var label = $(this).attr('title');

        dataLayer.push({

'event':'GAevent',

   'eventCategory': 'How To Box', //create a datalayer variable macro called

   'eventAction': 'Click', //datalayer variable macro called eventAction

   'eventLabel': {{url}} // datalayer variable macro called eventLabel
        });
    });
</script>
```

This tag fires on all pages and it works - GA Category and Action fire as expected.

Notice me trying to be smart with {{url}}. Previously I had just added a quoted string. But, now I would like the event label to be the page that the event was fired on. Now my understanding was that the power of GTM is that we can do this with Macros.

The url macro appears in GTM. Macro name: url, macro type: url, component type: url. I don't know what all that means but they seem to be defaults and I took it to mean "include the url macro and the page will be called".

Event label is not coming through. I had expected to see, in this particular instance, the home page appear as event label (because that's where I was firing it from).

How do I dynamically pull in URL as event label when people click the specified anchor tag?

Site in question is here. Links in question are the iPhone and Android App links to the right in a grey box. http://tinyurl.com/o6ycy39

Comment: Can't help with your problem (code looks alright) but about the macro: "macro name" is an arbitrary name;  "macro type" means the macro pulls it's value from the adress bar of the browser (other types are for example events which geht their value from the event property of the data layer), component type let's you specify which part of the url (full url, protocol, host, path) you want to use (would propably be better to use "path" in your case). And GA tracks the site where the event is recorded in any case, so using the label to store the url is a bit of a waste.

Comment: Btw. this is not the tag where the event is sent to analytics - this just puts variables on the datalayer. To debug we would need to see the tag with the actual ga-send call.

Comment: @EikePierstorff what is "this tag"? The code snippet above? The tag with the actual GA send call? Not sure what you mean here. I have a GAevents tag which is a UA tag, track type event, rule: {{event}} equals GAevent and where each parameter (category, action, label etc have a corresponding macro e.g. Category: {{eventCategory}}

Comment: that's what I meant - since macro names are case sensitive it's worth to doublecheck. Maybe you could pro term replace the url macro with window.location just to test if the problem is with the custom tag or with the event tag.

Comment: OK looks like I got this working. Well, kinda. I just changed {{url}} to {{url path}}. That's it. Not sure why just {{url} was not working. Thanks for the input @EikePierstorff GTM is a little confusing

Comment: Have you tried `'eventLabel': window.location.href`?

Comment: Thanks for thr tip Mike. This ship sailed and I don't remember what I ended up doing but will remember window.location in any future instalation